# I used another power adapter for my soda machine

Tags: power-supply, voltage, electric-machine

I have a soda machine that was working perfectly until I decided to use another adapter just to check if it still worked. Now the soda machine is not working anymore, please help!

This is the incorrect adapter that I used:

[image]

This is the original adapter of the machine which worked correctly:

[image]

This is the specification plate on the machine:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 6):

You have almost certainly damaged the sodastream machine.
It you are lucky you may have blown an internal fuse.

- The correct adapter has a 6.5V DC output.
  This is shown on the adapter and on the machine.
- The adapter that you trued to use is rated at 19 V DC output.
  This is far higher than 6.5V and would be expected to cause damage.

I recommend that you ask a competent repairer to determine whether the machine is repairable.

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting to know why this was downvoted. The advice is correct and helpful. If it's worth a downvote then the OP would benefit from knowing why.